# How to enforce Gregorian calendar in all cultures in asp.net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, regional-settings

We have an asp.net Core website which requires having different cultures available but we are having a problem when saving dates to the database due to different calendars.

How can we enforce the Gregorian calendar even if culture was changed?

```
    private readonly CultureInfo[] _supportedCultures = {
        new CultureInfo("ar"),
        new CultureInfo("en")
    };
```

what we want to is to make "ar" or any other culture use "en" dateformat...

Thank You

Comment: Don't allow changing of UICulture?

Comment: @Tseng but we would like to allow users to change the culture to have a different language but keep the dateformat to us

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can always use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`/`CultureInfo.InvariantUiCulture`, or whatever your preferred culture is.

`IStringLocalizer<T>` has a `.WithCulture(...)` method, so you can create a localizer with that specific culture.

Something like this (untested):

```
IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> localizer = ..;
var invariantLocalizer = localizer.WithCulture(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// where "ShowDate" is "Today is {0}" in the resx
var neutralLocalizer = invariantLocalizer["ShowDate", DateTime.Now];
```

In MVC Views you can define it globally for each view in `Views/_ViewImports.cshtml`/`Views/_ViewStart.cshtml`:

```
@inject Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility.TelemetryConfiguration TelemetryConfiguration
@inject IHtmlLocalizer<Startup> Localizer
@{ 
    var InvariantLocalizer = Localizer.WithCulture(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

Optionally you can also set the calendar of a given culture.

```
var current = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;
current.DateTimeFormat.Calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
```

as shown in the [Dates and calendars](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/working-with-calendars#dates-and-calendars).

Comment: Like I said, you can create an instance of the localizer with a different culture by calling `.WithCulture(newCulture)` method. The returned localizer will use that culture then

Comment: can you please modify your answer to include an example that would work if I modify Startup.cs? thanks

Comment: Try out the last edit, by setting the calendar within the startup (where you setup your LocalizationOptions